# Yii2 Restful app, on a page without data, it still gives out data from previous pages

Tags: php, rest, yii2

I made a restful application, when some one requests this url

```
localhost/myapp/web/order?page=1
```

it gives the first page and it's ok, but when requesting a page with nothing on it, it still gives out data to last page

for example if we had 6 pages, and request for page 9 was given, has data on it but data if from another page.

I need to config my app to not return any thing when a page with nothing on it is requested, How can I do it?

my `config/web.php` looks like this :

```
    'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'enableStrictParsing' => false,
        'rules' => [
            'OPTIONS <controller:\w+>' => '<controller>/options',
            'OPTIONS <controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/options',
            'GET <controller:\w+>' => '<controller>/index',
            'GET <controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
            'POST <controller:\w+>' => '<controller>/create',
            'PUT,PATCH <controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/update',
            'DELETE <controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/delete',
        ],
    ],
```

and my controller looks like this :

```
namespace app\controllers;

use yii\rest\ActiveController;

class OrderController extends ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'app\models\Order';

    public $serializer = [
        'class' => 'yii\rest\Serializer',
        'collectionEnvelope' => 'items',
    ];

    public function actions()
    {
        $actions = parent::actions();

        unset($actions['create']); // no need for creating here
        return $actions;
    }
}
```

Comment: There are two ways of returning data
1. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-quick-start.html using active controller listed on this url. check your rule
2. using Controller class.

Comment: modify you rule 
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'enableStrictParsing' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => 'order'],
    ],
]